# Как сделать кнопку на подобие Сграбь.ру ?

Tags: php

Доброго времени. Я почти доделал свой парсер) осталась одна загвоздка.
Как сделать? чтобы я заходил к примеру на страницу, откуда мне нужно парсить,
с неё переходил по кнопке на подобие сграбь ру и стартовал парсинг. 
Хотя бы соображениями поделитесь))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрим ссылку на сграбь.ру:

```
javascript:(function(){window.name=document.location+'|||'+document.body.innerHTML;document.location='http://www.sgrab.ru/download.php';})()
```

Смысловая нагрузка идет только в строке:

```
document.location='http://www.sgrab.ru/download.php';
```

Т.е. происходит переадресация на страницу `http://www.sgrab.ru/download.php`, дальше скрипт смотрит реферер.

Comment: немного не понял как этим пользоваться)))у меня скрипт на пыхыпы. как взаимодействовать?куда будет приходить исходный код?

Comment: @Сашка смотри в чем тут вся соль: У тебя в ссылке будет содержаться javascript код, который будет делать перенаправление со страницы ютуба на твою страницу. При этом ты у тебя уже сможешь достать реферер - такая штука, которая содержит предыдущую просмотренную страницу. На пхп это выглядит так: 

>$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. 

Получается: юзер переходит со страницы ютуба на твою страницу, перенося в http_referer ссылку на предыдущую страницу. Тебе остается взять эту ссылку, и распарсить контент, который находится по этой ссылке.

Comment: про реферер понятно а куда вставлять javascript не пойму ))видимо нужно приступать к изучению))) мой скрипт начинается с этого
$code = file_get_contents("ishodnik.txt");

Comment: Ну javascript для клиента, чтобы он перенес ссылку в закладки,  содержащую этот js код, по которой потом мог кликать.

Comment: <a href="ТУТ ДОЛЖЕН БЫТЬ JS???">Украсть</a>

Comment: @Сашка ага, так. Эту ссылку юзер потом должен будет перенести в закладки, чтобы с любого места была возможность на неё нажать.

Comment: а если мой парсер переходит по страницам?одну спарсил пошел на другую. дальше как обращаться к исходному коду следующей страницы?